# Conversion error when i call a stored procedure from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure called `lastID` like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lastID(@id varchar(64) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @f VARCHAR(64);

    SELECT TOP 1 @f = work_id 
    FROM workorder 
    WHERE (RIGHT(work_id,2)) = (RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2)) 
    ORDER BY work_id DESC;

    IF(@f IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @f = 'No work orders';
        SET @id = @f;
        RETURN @id;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @id = @f;
        RETURN @id;
    END
END
```

This stored procedure returns the last id from the table workorder, now I'm trying to execute this procedure in C#, this is the code:

```
private void lastWorkId()
{
    String strConnString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=recalls;Integrated Security=true";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "lastID";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        String id = cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString();
        lastid.Text = id.ToString(); //Putting the return value into a label
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I don't know what are wrong with my code, because an exception is displayed, and this says

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' OT- 003-16 ' to data type int

Comment: It's telling you that it can't convert that string to an int. What line is your exception occurring on? Debug it.

Comment: in this line: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: What is `work_id` in your table?

Comment: A varchar primary key

Comment: If you execute your stored proc using SSMS (without C#), pass in fake parameter inputs... does it work?

Comment: Oh! i saw the same error..., but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about my first answer, here is the updated answer:

Your stored procedure is setup with an `OUTPUT` parameter of type `VARCHAR(64)`.

Within your proc you have a couple of `RETURN @id;` statements, which is actually returning a `VARCHAR(64)`. You only need to set your `OUTPUT` variable within the stored procedure. The `RETURN` statement expects an integer expression. Here's the updated fixed sproc using `OUTPUT` appropriately:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[lastID](@id varchar(64) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @f VARCHAR(64);
SELECT TOP 1 @f = work_id FROM workorder WHERE (RIGHT(work_id,2)) = (RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2)) ORDER BY work_id DESC;
IF(@f IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    SET @f = 'No work orders';
    SET @id = @f;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @id = @f;
    END
END
```

Comment: Oh! Im trying this: (RIGHT(CAST(Year(getDate()) AS varchar(64)),2)), but still doesnt work

Comment: Edited answer with correction. Basically, you don't need to return anything, since you're using an `OUTPUT` parameter. Simply set the parameter somewhere in your stored proc, and it'll be set for use outside the sproc.

Answer (score 0):

Error is basically should get fixed by cast

```
((RIGHT(work_id,2)) as int)
```

But code can be further condensed and improved.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lastID(@id varchar(64) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = isnull(work_id , 'No work orders') FROM workorder WHERE cast ((RIGHT(work_id,2)) as int)= (RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2)) ORDER BY work_id DESC;
    RETURN @id;
END
```